# getting SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restful-authentication

I am just writing a client method and invoking the POST method. But i am facing the below error.

When i test the webservices url though postman its working. Only in my client code its giving error.

Mar 29, 2016 5:39:27 PM        org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class org.json.JSONObject, genericType=class org.json.JSONObject.
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class org.json.JSONObject, genericType=class org.json.JSONObject.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:499)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:448)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:349)
    at test.restful.webservices.TESTClient.testUpdateUser(TESTClient.java:58)
    at test.restful.webservices.TESTClient.main(TESTClient.java:89)

Here is my Code:

```
  private void testUpdateUser(){
      FormBean sample = new FormBean();  
      sample.setFORM_LONG_DESC("FrmIssCMNEW");       
      JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(sample);
      System.out.println("Json ===>>"+jo);
      String callResult = client
          .target(REST_SERVICE_URL)
          .path("/Add")
          .queryParam("formcode", "FrmIssCMNEW")
          .queryParam("dsnID","OFSBGRC")
          .queryParam("version","1")
          .queryParam("longdesc","testing by me")
         .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
         .post(Entity.entity(jo,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON),
            String.class);

  Post Method:
  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)   
  @Path("/Add")
  public String save
  (     @QueryParam("formcode") String formcode,
        @QueryParam("version") int version,
        @QueryParam("dsnID") String dsnID,
        @QueryParam("longdesc") String longdesc)
    {   
       /* my code */
           return "Display from POST method  <> "+"FormID :"+fb.getFORM_ID()+" -->> FormLong Description :"+fb.getFORM_LONG_DESC();

   }
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: It seems a library import problem, please post also your pom.xml

Comment: Thanks For your quick response but I am Not using maven. and i have imported all jersey jars. and get, delete are working fine. only for post i am getting error.

Comment: To add JSON suport to Jersey you need to add a media provider: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html. I Recommend MOXy (jersey-media-moxy)